# php .htaccess Redirect page for Social media crawling

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a htaccess code which i got from [here](https://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/enable-rich-social-sharing-in-your-angularjs-app)

The scenario is that if the access is from a social media website agent, then it should redirect to autorender.php.

For eg : if a social media crawler tries to access https://mywebsite.com/details/23. Then it should redirect to autorender page https://mywebsite.com/autorender.php?id=23. But if the access is from normal users it can go to the url. it is done for rich social media sharing option.
My problem is when i try to use the url https://mywebsite.com/details/23 in my facebook post, it is showing page not found.
[image]

My .htaccess code is given below

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

# allow social media crawlers to work by redirecting them to a server-rendered static version on the page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteRule details/(\d*)$ https://mywebsite.com/autorender.php?id=$1 [P]


# Required to allow direct-linking of pages so they can be processed by Angular
# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d  
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]  

</ifModule>
```

And autorender.php file

```
<?php

$APIBASE = "https://api.mywebsite.com/";
$id;
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
     $id = $_GET['id'];
     $jsonData = getData($APIBASE , $id);

}

function getData($apiBase, $id ) {
$rawData = file_get_contents($apiBase."api/getPostbyIdGet.php?pid=".$id);
return json_decode($rawData);
}
makePage($jsonData, $APIBASE ,"https://mywebsite.com/details/".$id);
function makePage($data, $siteRoot, $redirectUrl) {

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                       <head>
                                  <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $data[0]->postname; ?>" />
                                  <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $data[0]->description; ?>" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $redirectUrl ?>" />
 </head>
<body>
<h2><?php echo $data[0]->postname; ?></h2>
<p><?php echo $data[0]->description; ?></p>
</body>

</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

ps : php version 5.3

Comment: That `.htaccess` snippet only handles the redirect stuff. Where's the rest of your `.htaccess` for normal visitors?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the code and question now. Thanks

Comment: Can you give us the domain name in question so we can see it in action?